# Removeing http_access_yyyy_mm_dd.log file in wso2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have one problem with `API` Manager.

I don't want to have logs of requests and responses in `API` Manager, because those log files are so big and I encounter files with `20G`. I tried to comment `Catalina` access file, which is in `repositoy/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
       directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs"
       prefix="http_access_"
       suffix=".log"
       pattern="combined"/>
```

Unfortunately, after commenting the above code, only `http_access_.log` file didn't created, but `http_access_yyyy_mm_dd.log` was created and requests saved in it. I tried to change directory of above file, too. Only file `http_access_.log` saved in new directory, and `http_access_yyyy_mm_dd.log` is still created in the `${carbon.home}/repository/logs` directory.

How can change configuration of `http_access_yyyy_mm_dd.log` in `wso2` `API` Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Apache Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve),

> The name of the file is composed by concatenation of the configured
>   prefix, timestamp and suffix

You can simply comment out the code snippet which you have mentioned which can be found in `<PRODUCT_HOME>\repository\conf\tomcat\catalina-server.xml`.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs" prefix="http_access_" suffix=".log"b pattern="combined"/>
```

In simple comment the above code snippet in the mentioned file path and restart the WSO2 APIM server.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tested it more. It works in APIM, but in distributed APIM, it didn't work. I disabled it through logging configuration form. There is not any access files, anymore.